# Three.js CircleBufferGeometry not working with few elements

Tags: three.js

This code works fine:

```
  circlesGeometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(10, 32);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circlesGeometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

Then I trying add position:

```
  circlesGeometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(10, 32);
  circlesGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([0, 0, 0]), 3));
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circlesGeometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

I have an error:

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f9abda5ea00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION :
>   glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) says:

*.addAttribute ( name, attribute )*

*Adds an attribute to this geometry. Use this rather than the attributes property, because an internal hashmap of .attributes is maintained to speed up iterating over attributes.*

and, digging into [BufferGeometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/BufferGeometry.js), we can see that `.addAttribute()` does next (shortly):

```
addAttribute: function ( name, attribute ) {

    ... 
    this.attributes[ name ] = attribute; // here you set the property

    return this;

}
```

As your buffer geometry already has `position` property (object) of `attributes` property (object), when you do this:

```
circlesGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([0, 0, 0]), 3));
```

you simply replace the existing `position` object with the new one whose `array` contains just 3 items. In simple words, an object can't contain several properties of the same name.

As you created `THREE.CircleBufferGeometry()`, it already has filled `index` property, containing indices of vertices for faces. In your case, its `array` property has 96 elements. Element 31's value is 12. But, when you replaced `position` attribute with the new array, which contains just 3 elements [0..2], there is no element with index of 12.

Comment: I use this example. https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry
For lines and BufferGeometry this example works fine.

Comment: [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_lines) one? In the beginning, `THREE.BufferGeometry()` was created, which contains empty `attribute` propery, and then it filled with `position` and `color` properties, whose values for their `array`s created in loop. But when you create `THREE.CircleBufferGeometr(10, 32)`, you already have there filled `position` attribute.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/q5t19kyt/) just compare objects in browser console log. Pay attention to the `index` attribute in both geometries.

Comment: So, ok, CircleBufferGeometry it's an short method to create an object. Wrapper for BufferGeometry, correct? If I want to create about 100 circles I can't use BufferGeometry like I use it for lines? For this I must use, for example, array of CircleBufferGeometry? Something like this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html

Comment: I see no obstacles to create 1000 circles of `THREE.CircleBufferGeometry()` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/q5t19kyt/)

Comment: Sure, it's not a problem. I thought use buffer for all circles it's more efficient for performance. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to follow @WestLangley's suggestion: Don't care about performance as long as there are real problems with it.